# Printing limits of Integral Types in C

Tags: beginner, c, formatting, integer

I intend to demonstrate the proper way to use format specifiers for different data types and also display the respective limits. This is meant to be an example.

### `limitdemo.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN "20"

const char line_char = '=';

void print_line(const size_t len)
{
    for (size_t index = 0; index < len; ++index) {
        putchar(line_char);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main()
{
    // For Unix-based systems, replace %[...]Iu with %[...]zu
    // The standard types - signed
    printf("\n\n%-9s | Bytes | %"LEN"s | %"LEN"s\n", "Type", "Minimum", "Maximum");
    print_line(63);
    printf("char      | %5Iu | %"LEN"hhd | %"LEN"hhd\n", sizeof(char), CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
    printf("short     | %5Iu | %"LEN"hd | %"LEN"hd\n", sizeof(char), SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("int       | %5Iu | %"LEN"d | %"LEN"d\n", sizeof(int), INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("long      | %5Iu | %"LEN"ld | %"LEN"ld\n", sizeof(long), LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("long long | %5Iu | %"LEN"lld | %"LEN"lld\n", sizeof(long long), LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
    
    // The standard types - unsigned
    printf("\n\n%-18s | Bytes | %"LEN"s\n", "Type", "Maximum");
    print_line(49);
    printf("unsigned char      | %5Iu | %"LEN"hhu\n", sizeof(unsigned char), UCHAR_MAX);
    printf("unsigned short     | %5Iu | %"LEN"hu\n", sizeof(unsigned char), USHRT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned int       | %5Iu | %"LEN"u\n", sizeof(unsigned int), UINT_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long      | %5Iu | %"LEN"lu\n", sizeof(unsigned long), ULONG_MAX);
    printf("unsigned long long | %5Iu | %"LEN"llu\n", sizeof(unsigned long long), ULLONG_MAX);

    // The fixed-width types signed and unsigned
    printf("\n\nWidth  | %"LEN"s | %"LEN"s\n", "Signed Max", "Unsigned Max");
    print_line(52);
    printf(" 8 bit | %"LEN"hhd | %"LEN"hhu\n", INT8_MAX, UINT8_MAX);
    printf("16 bit | %"LEN"hd | %"LEN"hu\n", INT16_MAX, UINT16_MAX);
    printf("32 bit | %"LEN"d | %"LEN"u\n", INT32_MAX, UINT32_MAX);
    printf("64 bit | %"LEN"lld | %"LEN"llu\n", INT64_MAX, UINT64_MAX);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> **Note:** For Unix-based (non-Windows) systems, use `zu` instead of `Iu`.

### Output (may vary on your system)

```
Type      | Bytes |              Minimum |              Maximum
===============================================================
char      |     1 |                 -128 |                  127
short     |     1 |               -32768 |                32767
int       |     4 |          -2147483648 |           2147483647
long      |     4 |          -2147483648 |           2147483647
long long |     8 | -9223372036854775808 |  9223372036854775807


Type               | Bytes |              Maximum
=================================================
unsigned char      |     1 |                  255
unsigned short     |     1 |                65535
unsigned int       |     4 |           4294967295
unsigned long      |     4 |           4294967295
unsigned long long |     8 | 18446744073709551615


Width  |           Signed Max |         Unsigned Max
====================================================
 8 bit |                  127 |                  255
16 bit |                32767 |                65535
32 bit |           2147483647 |           4294967295
64 bit |  9223372036854775807 | 18446744073709551615
```

### My question

How do I make the code less repetitive and better organized? I would also be grateful for advice on any aspect of the code, suggestions for alternate approach or better ways of doing it. That includes a better way to render the tables.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior for the fixed-width types. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9225648.

Comment: @Roland You're right about using the PRI Macros. I forgot to use them.

Comment: You have a copy paste bug: notice your program output shows Bytes for short as 1 instead of 2 (same for unsigned short).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make the code less repetitive and better organized?

1. Rather then bury magic numbers 9, 18, 20 in format specifiers, consider `"*"` for the width.  Then compiled code could pass in the computed width.
2. Similar thought for `print_line(63);`

   ```
   printf("\n\n");
   int nn = printf("%-9s | Bytes | %"LEN"s | %"LEN"s\n", "Type", inimum", "Maximum");
   print_line(nn);
   ```
3. Not too easy to re-organize too much without violating coding goal of "demonstrate the proper way to use format specifiers for different data types".  Perhaps a helper function to print the common prefix and size to un-clutter the demonstration.

   ```
   // printf("long long | %5Iu | %"LEN"lld | %"LEN"lld\n", sizeof(long long), LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
   prefix("long long", sizeof(long long));
   printf("%"LEN"lld | %"LEN"lld\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX);
   ```
4. For printing info about *fixed width types*, I'd recommend to group them with the above *signed*, *unsigned* groups rather than establish a new table layout.  Also call them "int8_t", "uint64_t", etc.

> I would also be grateful for advice on any aspect of the code, suggestions for alternate approach or better ways of doing it.

4. Invalid print specifier `"%5Iu"`.
   This led to "warning: unknown conversion type character 'I' in format" on my Windows based compiler.  The use of `"%5Iu"` may work well with some compliers as a valid extension, but that is a compiler issue and not an OS issue as suggested with "For Unix-based (non-Windows) systems, use zu instead of Iu".  Yet since all `sizeof()` are small here, code could use `%d` and `(int) sizeof(xxx)` and avoid the `z` vs. `I` issue.
5. The fixed point types should use the macros such as `PRId8, PRIu64` found in `<inttypes.h>` rather than guess the `printf` specifier. [@Roland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183966/printing-limits-of-integral-types-in-c#comment350331_183966)

   ```
   // printf("64 bit | %"LEN"lld | %"LEN"llu\n", INT64_MAX, UINT64_MAX);
   printf("64 bit | %"LEN PRId64 " | %"LEN PRIu64 "\n", INT64_MAX, UINT64_MAX);
   ```
6. The use of `#define LEN "20"` for width is relying on integer types being  64 bits or less.  Highly portable code would adjust this.  It is not unreasonable to see an upcoming compiler use `long long` as 128 bit.
7. `char` is not necessarily a *signed* type.  Instead of `char`, `signed char` would have made more sense.  Further, `hhd` is not necessarily the matching numeric specifier for `char`.  Likely need conditional code to handle `char` well.

   ```
   // printf("char      | %5Iu | %"LEN"hhd | %"LEN"hhd\n", 
   //     sizeof(char), CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX);
   printf("signed char| %5Iu | %"LEN"hhd | %"LEN"hhd\n", 
       sizeof(signed char), SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX);

   #if CHAR_MAX == SCHAR_MAX
     .... print using hhd
   #else
     .... print using hhu
   #endif
   ```
8. For completeness I'd expect the min/max type of `signed char, intmax_t, uintmax_t`.  `_Bool, size_t, ptrdiff_t, intptr_t, uintptr` are some other common candidates for consideration.
9. For the rare platform where `CHAR_BIT != 8`, Instead of listing "bytes", perhaps use "bits" and `sizeof(xxx)*CHAR_BIT`.  On such rare machines note that fixed width types like `int8_t`, etc. are individually optional.
10. [@JS1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183966/printing-limits-of-integral-types-in-c/184056#comment350535_183966). Certain typo

    ```
    // printf("short   | %5Iu | %"LEN"hd | %"LEN"hd\n", sizeof(char), SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("short   | %5Iu | %"LEN"hd | %"LEN"hd\n", sizeof(short), SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    ```

---

Putting most of these ideas together.  Improvements possible - just to give OP ideas.

```
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

void print_line(int n) {
  const char line_char = '=';
  while (n-- > 0) {
    putchar(line_char);
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

void prefix(int w, const char *pre, size_t sz) {
  printf("%-*s | %4u | ", w, pre, (int)(sz * CHAR_BIT));
}

int main(void) {
  int type_width = (int) strlen("unsigned long long");
  int max_width = (int) ceil(log10((double) UINTMAX_MAX));
  int min_width = (int) ceil(log10(-1.0 * INTMAX_MIN)) + 1;

  int nn = printf("%-*s | Bits | %*s | %*s\n",
      type_width, "Type", max_width, "Maximum", min_width, "Minimum");
  print_line(nn - 1);
  prefix(type_width, "signed char", sizeof(signed char));
  printf("%*hhd | %*hhd\n", max_width, SCHAR_MAX, min_width, SCHAR_MIN);
#if CHAR_MAX == SCHAR_MAX
  prefix(type_width, "char", sizeof(char));
  printf("%*hhd | %*hhd\n", max_width, SCHAR_MAX, min_width, SCHAR_MIN);
#endif
  prefix(type_width, "short", sizeof(short));
  printf("%*hd | %*hd\n", max_width, SHRT_MAX, min_width, SHRT_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "int", sizeof(int));
  printf("%*d | %*d\n", max_width, INT_MAX, min_width, INT_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "long", sizeof(long));
  printf("%*ld | %*ld\n", max_width, LONG_MAX, min_width, LONG_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "long long", sizeof(long long));
  printf("%*lld | %*lld\n", max_width, LLONG_MAX, min_width, LLONG_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "intmax_t", sizeof(intmax_t));
  printf("%*jd | %*jd\n", max_width, INTMAX_MAX, min_width, INTMAX_MIN);

  prefix(type_width, "ptrdiff_t", sizeof(ptrdiff_t));
  printf("%*td | %*td\n", max_width, PTRDIFF_MAX, min_width, PTRDIFF_MIN);

  prefix(type_width, "int8_t", sizeof(int8_t));
  printf("%*" PRId8 " | %*" PRId8 "\n", max_width, INT8_MAX, min_width, INT8_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "int16_t", sizeof(int16_t));
  printf("%*" PRId16 " | %*" PRId16 "\n", max_width, INT16_MAX, min_width, INT16_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "int32_t", sizeof(int32_t));
  printf("%*" PRId32 " | %*" PRId32 "\n", max_width, INT32_MAX, min_width, INT32_MIN);
  prefix(type_width, "int64_t", sizeof(int64_t));
  printf("%*" PRId64 " | %*" PRId64 "\n", max_width, INT64_MAX, min_width, INT64_MIN);

  prefix(type_width, "intptr_t", sizeof(intptr_t));
  printf("%*" PRIdPTR " | %*" PRIdPTR "\n", max_width, INTPTR_MAX, min_width, INTPTR_MIN);

  puts("");
  nn = printf("%-*s | Bits | %*s\n", type_width, "Type", max_width, "Maximum");
  print_line(nn - 1);
#if CHAR_MAX == UCHAR_MAX
  prefix(type_width, "char", sizeof(char));
  printf("%*hhu\n", max_width, UCHAR_MAX);
#endif
  prefix(type_width, "unsigned char", sizeof(unsigned char));
  printf("%*hhu\n", max_width, UCHAR_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "unsigned short", sizeof(unsigned short));
  printf("%*hu\n", max_width, USHRT_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "unsigned", sizeof(unsigned));
  printf("%*u\n", max_width, UINT_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "unsigned long", sizeof(unsigned long));
  printf("%*lu\n", max_width, ULONG_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "unsigned long long", sizeof(unsigned long long));
  printf("%*llu\n", max_width, ULLONG_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "uintmax_t", sizeof(uintmax_t));
  printf("%*ju\n", max_width, UINTMAX_MAX);

  prefix(type_width, "size_t", sizeof(size_t));
  printf("%*zu\n", max_width, SIZE_MAX);

  prefix(type_width, "uint8_t", sizeof(uint8_t));
  printf("%*" PRIu8 "\n", max_width, UINT8_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "uint16_t", sizeof(uint16_t));
  printf("%*" PRIu16 "\n", max_width, UINT16_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "uint32_t", sizeof(uint32_t));
  printf("%*" PRIu32 "\n", max_width, UINT32_MAX);
  prefix(type_width, "uint64_t", sizeof(uint64_t));
  printf("%*" PRIu64 "\n", max_width, UINT64_MAX);

  prefix(type_width, "uintptr_t", sizeof(uintptr_t));
  printf("%*" PRIuPTR "\n", max_width, UINTPTR_MAX);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output

```
Type               | Bits |              Maximum |              Minimum
=======================================================================
signed char        |    8 |                  127 |                 -128
char               |    8 |                  127 |                 -128
short              |   16 |                32767 |               -32768
int                |   32 |           2147483647 |          -2147483648
long               |   32 |           2147483647 |          -2147483648
long long          |   64 |  9223372036854775807 | -9223372036854775808
intmax_t           |   64 |  9223372036854775807 | -9223372036854775808
ptrdiff_t          |   32 |           2147483647 |          -2147483648
int8_t             |    8 |                  127 |                 -128
int16_t            |   16 |                32767 |               -32768
int32_t            |   32 |           2147483647 |          -2147483648
int64_t            |   64 |  9223372036854775807 | -9223372036854775808
intptr_t           |   32 |           2147483647 |          -2147483648

Type               | Bits |              Maximum
================================================
unsigned char      |    8 |                  255
unsigned short     |   16 |                65535
unsigned           |   32 |           4294967295
unsigned long      |   32 |           4294967295
unsigned long long |   64 | 18446744073709551615
uintmax_t          |   64 | 18446744073709551615
size_t             |   32 |           4294967295
uint8_t            |    8 |                  255
uint16_t           |   16 |                65535
uint32_t           |   32 |           4294967295
uint64_t           |   64 | 18446744073709551615
uintptr_t          |   32 |           4294967295
```